# How to print an attribute of an object?

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to learn Java/OOP by doing. I'm attempting to print the name attribute from my "bears" object. I've been looking around on Google, but am not sure what to search for. Everything except the print statement *should* be correct.

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(NFCnorth.bears.name);
    }
}

class Team
{
    String name;

    public Team(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }
}

class NFCnorth
{
    private String divisionName="NFC North";

     Team vikings=new Team("Minnesota Vikings");
     Team bears=new Team("Chicago Bears");
     Team packers=new Team("Green Bay Packers");
     Team lions=new Team("Detroit Lions");
}
```

Comment: The encapsulation is fine as-is, it's the Data Hiding that is violated.

Answer (score 0):

You could just access it (assuming it's visible from your `main`):

```
System.out.println(bears.team);
```

But the idiomatic approach would be to provide the class `Team` with a getter for its name:

```
public class Team {
    String name;

    public Team(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

and use it from your main:

```
System.out.println(bears.getName());
```

Comment: It's always these typos haha, getName* and return name*

Comment: Np, I actually envy you for that, wish i could reach a level of expertise where the only bugs i have in my well written code is silly typos ;P

Comment: @RafatRifaie even experts write bugs man, be prepared for that haha

Answer (score 0):

You need to either do

```
System.out.println(new NFCnorth().bears.name);
```

or make the bears field in NFCnorth static like this:

```
static Team bears=new Team("Chicago Bears");
```

In OOP there are objects of various classes. Each object of a given class has the same set of fields (which can have different values). You defined a class NFCnorth to have field bears so every object of this class will have such field. To get an object of class NFCnorth you need to create it with `new NFCnorth()`. A class itself does not have those fields so NFCnorth.bears is illegal.

Marking field as static means that it will be a field in a class and then NFCnorth.bears will be ok.

Answer (score -1):

Either use constants:

```
 public static final Team VIKINGS = new Team("Minnesota Vikings");
 public static final Team BEARS = new Team("Chicago Bears");
 public static final Team PACKERS = new Team("Green Bay Packers");
 public static final Team LIONS = new Team("Detroit Lions");
```

or you need to instantiate `NFCnorth` first. Also, in good OOP you should apply encapsulation and create getters for your attributes (at least in Java, some other languages use different conventions for getters, where there is no syntactical difference between accessing an attribute and accessing a property through a getter):

```
new NFCnorth().getBears().getName()
```